# How to create a big file to fill disk to the full on windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

For example, I have a Lumia 920, its total space is 32G, and available free space is 24G.
Now I want to create some files to filling disk to the full, how can I create 24G files as quickly as possilbe? I tried, but very slowly. :-(

As far as I know, one app (see below link) can do that, but I really can't understand how does he do it? Write isolated storage is very slow slow. Could you give me some advices?

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/%E7%BC%93%E5%AD%98%E6%B8%85%E7%90%86/b790919d-8ec8-40d8-b97a-10c466cedca8

Comment: Why would you do that? To test your app in low disk space?

Comment: I want to do some performance testing. :D

Comment: I think you can test it in emulator

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the file like thisand write a single byte:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\yourfilename", FileMode.CreateNew);
fs.Seek(2048L * 1024 * 1024, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fs.WriteByte(0);
fs.Close();
```

This example will create a 2GB file with a single byte of content !